# Extract windows event log in CSV

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I extract Windows event log in CSV format?
There are many pages explain using "| export-csv xxxx.csv".
But I need csv file format same as extracted when I choose "Save All Events As .." -> "Save As Type = CSV".

[image]

Is there any command for it?
or do I need to add parameters to export-csv command?

Comment: Well, what's the difference in those CSV formats?

Comment: Well first you can do a manual export. check what the csv file generated looks like then you use `Get-EventLog` cmdlet and pipe that to `Select`, structure the output the way you want it to appear in the file and then pipe that to `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: In the following answer I've used the term properties as this is the correct PowerShell terminology, but a property will turn into a column in the resultant csv.

The problem you are encountering is twofold:

1. Get-EventLog retrieves more information than the export to csv from the GUI does.

To solve this you need to identify the properties you need by looking at the csv file which are 'Level, Date and Time, Source, Event ID,    Task Category'

There is also a last column in the GUI exported file which isn't named, but appears to be the event 'message'.

You then need to cut down the data that is given to you by the PoSH command to the same subset that the GUI gives you.

This is enabled by piping the information to the Select-Object command:

Note the application log is just used as an example here.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select-Object -Property EntryType,TimeGenerated,Source,EventID,Category,Message
```

The order of the properties here is important as that will be the order when you export the data to csv.

This should get you the relevant data that you need in the right order.

2. The second problem is that your column headings are different as the GUI and PowerShell have different names for the properties.  e.g level (from GUI) and EntryType (from Powershell) powershell is probably giving you the correct underlying name which the GUI is translating to another.  If you wish to change the property name you can also do this with the select-object cmdlet.

So to change the name EntryType to Label in your data you could do the following:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select-Object -Property @{n = 'Label'; e = { $_.Entrytype }}
```

Note this will only display the Label property. I've reduced the properties to one for clarity

To change the datetime property as well as label:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select-Object -Property @{n = 'Label'; e = { $_.Entrytype }}, @{n = 'Date and Time'; e = { $_.TimeGenerated }}
```

You can follow this method for the other properties.

To export the data to csv, you now just need to pipe the result to export-CSV.  I've omitted the code to change the property names for clarity.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select-Object -Property EntryType,TimeGenerated,Source,EventID,Category,Message | Export-CSV -Path c:\events.csv -NoClobber
```

The -NoClobber on the end prevents PoSH putting in some metadata on the first line of the csv to help it confirm more to what you want.